# Is there way to set IdleTimeout in ignite XML configuration file?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I need to set idleTimeout at server level as the connections are not being closed properly by the client.

I found below link, but I am not sure how to set using XML configuration file.

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ClientConnectorConfiguration.html#setIdleTimeout-long-

Is there way to set IdleTimeout in ignite/GridGain XML configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure ClientConnectorConfiguration like this:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration" id="ignite.cfg">
    <property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
            ...
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For more details see [docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients#configuring-thin-client-connector)

Comment: Looks like "idleTimeOut" parameter is not there is section of the code.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients#configuring-thin-client-connector

Comment: There are only some parameters. Completed list of parameters you can find in javadocs - https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.11.1/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ClientConnectorConfiguration.html

Comment: @Raghavendra H, Do you have any other questions for this?